# Odd Python WSGI behavior resulting in double iteration

Tags: python, wsgi

The code below runs a simple WSGI app that increments both a local counter and a global counter. The purpose of this test is to make sure the app object is created fresh for each HTTP request, so the expected behavior is for the global counter to increment each request while the local counter should always be ‘1’, because it is only incremented once for each instantiation of the app class.

Actual result? Pretty much what I expected, but the surprise is that the global counter is getting incremented TWICE for each HTTP request after the first one. (The sequence is something like [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, . . .].) I know that the **iter**() method is only being called once per app object instantiation because the local variable is always ‘1’. So what’s going on?

This may not matter as all I really care about is making sure the WSGI container always creates a new object for each request and uses it only once, but it is really odd. I would like to know why.

I do not like unexplained side effects. Can someone give me some insight?

```
gctr = 0

class app(object):
    html = '''<html><head><title>Simple WSGI App Class Test</title></head>
    <body><h2>Simple WSGI App Class Test</h2>
    <p>module counter = {}</p>
    <p>global counter = {}</p>
    </body></html>'''
    ctr = 0

    def __init__(self, environ, start_response):
        self.environ = environ
        self.start = start_response

    def __iter__(self):
        self.start('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        global gctr
        gctr += 1
        self.ctr += 1
        yield self.html.format(self.ctr, gctr)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Using simple_server
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    srv = make_server('localhost', 8080, app)
    srv.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this is your browser making another request alongside the main one, which is also getting captured by your WSGI app - probably for favicon.ico. Log `self.environ['PATH_INFO']` to see the exact request.